# What is the meaning of the number 51 in the name of Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I've been using Area 51 for some time, but recently was curious about the name itself. I've read the discussion about the upgrade, which would result in "Area 52". So, what is the meaning of the number 51 in the name?

- Is it a version number?
- Is it the 51st site launched by StackExchange?
- Is it "51% progress", so the lowest number more than half?
- Has this numer any other special meaning?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_51

Comment: P.S. Area 52 is likely *not* going to be the name of the next-generation site. That was a name started by the community and the SE team has hinted more at a completely new name not related to "Area 51" whatsoever.

Comment: One of the posts I think @animuson is alluding to: [Next Generation of Area 51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/5102/44787)

Comment: I'm tempted to add [tag:faq-proposed] to this. It seems like a reasonable question to have around for non-Americans, if no-one else.

Comment: Argh, why no one reads the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: @Yannis: Why do you call it Area 51?
We like the little aliens. 

I doubt it explains anything...

Comment: Yes, it's a poor explanation, no argument there. Still, it's an explanation that at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Well, it didn't pointed me to any direction because it was for me 'it is named so because it is named so'...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is an area known for its secrecy and the famous conspiracy theorist that describe stories about it.

It is widely known in the US so just try Google or the Wikipedia entry, [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_51).

[image: area51]

Comment: So it means, we (all) famous conspiracy theorists.. Sounds cooool...

Comment: Oh sure, tell people you've been probed just once and you're a "conspiracy theorist" rather than a victim.....

Comment: @Bart Shhh. That is classified.

Comment: Good answer. I've learned something new. Those 51 was a senseless set of digits for me until now :)